# Set a different version to my jars at project deployment stage - Maven

Tags: maven, deployment, pom.xml, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a Maven deployment problem:

When I execute Maven deploy, Maven pushes all my jars to a remote repository under the project version which is specified in the POM files:

```
<version>version.x.y.z</version>
```

The problem is that I don't want to overwrite my previous jars every time I rebuild my project, I want to increment the version automatically every time I build as part of the building process.

(So, I don't want to use CLI tool such "Versions Maven Plugin" to change the pom files before the building process.) 
I have an environment variable, $project.buildnumber, that I can use to set the project version.

Is it possible to configure maven-deploy-plugin to automatically change the version (for instance using this environment variable)?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Are you using SNAPSHOT versions or things like `<version>1.2.3</version>` ?

Comment: More like the second option (    <version>1.2.3</version>).

Comment: Maven Build Number plugin.